# What does rigoruous but non-technical mean?

Tags: definition

Hi I find the above expression a bit confusing. I am considering buying a book and it says that it's  a rigorous but non-technical introduction to optimal stochastic control. Could someone explain ?
Is the book on Brownian Motion and stochastic calculus by Shereve technical and rigorous but the texts by Oksendal non-technical?

Comment: I’d say: A *rigorous* book states all claims clearly and gives careful proofs considering all important points. A *non-rigorous* book might only explain ideas, omit details in proof or use arguments appealing to imagination, common sense or faith. A *technical* book might use very specific language to state and prove its theorems involving strange or very local definitions, giving little hope of understanding a deeper meaning of them. A *non-technical* book makes rather short and clear statements and proofs, conceptual and (possibly) abstract in nature.

Comment: I think *technical* means that you cannot get much information out of it, except the main result. (There are no 'new' and 'elegant' techniques) whereas *rigorous* means that everything is detailed enough without any 'gaps'.

Comment: @k.stm My idea was that technical meant something which was rigorous and convoluted . Our professor sometimes does not prove certain results saying its technical , and really pissed me off during the class and I wanted to see all the proofs possible of the things we learned. Thank you guys